# Database query with two fields in the same table. Don't consider if any of the values are empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

The problem is I have a table with 4 columns. I have two search boxes.

Fields

```
FName
LName
Age
School
```

Text boxes

```
FName
School
```

If the user has inserted two values I want to get the intersect using both values. If only one value is present I want to have data using that value. I thought of not handling this in the application but with a stored procedure. 
I thought of using IF ELSE in the stored procedure or having sub queries. But not a solid solution. I need some guidance to think of a possible way. Thank you in advance.

Here is what I have tried. This is just the query I need to embed this in a stored procedure

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE FNname like '%TestFName%' 
INTERSECT SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE School LIKE '%TestSchool';
```

If the 'TestSchool" becomes null it takes all the records which full fill the first query.

If both values are missing it returns the whole table.

If both values are there it returns the specific data tuples.

Comment: First, MySQL or SQL Server? which one? second, what did you try?

Comment: Why are you using INTERSECT here? Did you teacher mandate you have to use that keyword? And again....which DBMS? The answers are not the same.

Comment: My problem is for SQL-Server. But I want to know solutions for both. I have updated my question.

Comment: No. I don't know any other way of doing that. Please guide me if there is

Comment: Did you see the answer below from Juan Carlos Oropeza??? If you want those rows where either of those is true just change the AND to an OR.

Comment: By far the best solution is to read this article from Gail Shaw on the topic of catch all queries. https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: @ShashithDarshana - Don't you have `NULL` in your `FName` and `School` columns in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it is as simple as this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENT 
WHERE FNname like '%TestFName%'
    AND School LIKE '%TestSchool%';
```

If use 'AND' rather than 'OR' it meets all the given conditions

Comment: We know Leading wildards are very bad but will `FNname like '%TestFName%' OR TestFName=''` perform better than   `FNname like '%TestFName%'`?

Comment: Probably about the same. The first predicate there is what would kill performance. The predicate to check for '' is not going to hurt performance.

Comment: It does not meet this condition

"If both values are there it returns the specific data tuples."

Comment: Change `OR` for `AND`

Comment: You have some very specific requirements but have not done a good posting what you expect as output. Several people have fired possible answers against an unknown table structure with an unknown desired output. If you want detailed assistance you need to provide those details with the table structure, sample data, desired output given a set of parameters against your sample data.

Comment: Yes that is my bad. I will try to correct the things you mentioned. 

Your answers is correct if 'AND' is used rather than 'OR' meets all my requirements. Thank you. I was very dumb to use two queries.

Comment: `If both values are missing it returns the whole table.` -- For this requirement, will this query show whole table considering that there are `NULL` values in both the columns?

Comment: From what is posted there are no NULLS in the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable
 WHERE (FName = @Fname OR @Fname = '') 
   AND (School = @School OR @School ='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I came up for my own problem.

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE FNname like '%TestFName%' 
INTERSECT SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE School LIKE '%TestSchool';
```

In here if the 'TestFName" becomes null it takes all the records which full fill the second query.

If the 'TestSchool" becomes null it takes all the records which full fill the first query.

If both values are missing it returns the whole table.

If both values are there it returns the specific data tuples.

Thank you. If there is a better way than this, please enlighten us.

Comment: First of all the leading wildcards are very bad for performance. If possible you should avoid that. Secondly, you are running two queries when you only need one.

Comment: Yes I see those as problems. Since it is a search box not a drop down in the UI  I need to have the wild cards. Yes if there is a way to avoid the two queries it is better

Comment: Try Sean answer, you only need a query. Mine was before you post there is a lIke involve :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE isnull(FNname, '') like '%' + isnull(@FNname, '') + '%' 
and isnull(School, '') like '%' + isnull(@School, '') + '%'
```

Use the parameters `@FNname` and `@School` in your stored procedure and use the above query in it.

Comment: I thing you misundestood the question. the one can be null are the parameters not the fields on db

Comment: I don't think so. Both columns may contain `NULL` normally, in that case, if `@School` is empty, then he wants all the records for this column, And if we don't use `isnull(School, '')`, `NULL` records will be excluded.